# icono aplicacion android studio

Tags: android

He creado un icono metiendo una imagen png para la aplicación mediante "image assets" , launcher icons y meta la imagen que meta, **en el móvil aparece el icono pequeño, bastante mas pequeño que el de las aplicaciones normales que tengo instaladas.**

Porque puede pasarme esto?

Comment: ¿Has [seguido los pasos indicados por Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html?hl=es-419#creating-launcher) para hacer este proceso? Cuando el proceso se realiza correctamente, debe haber en las diferentes carpetas `mipmap...` (ubicadas dentro de la carpeta `res` del proyecto) iconos del launcher de las diferentes resoluciones. También en el manifest debe haber algo como esto: `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

Comment: Si. Esta todo supuestamente bien

Answer (score 1):

Te aconsejo revises las [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html?hl=es), principalemente en este caso las de los iconos para lanzar la aplicación ([launcher icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html)). Para evitar se muestren pequeños o grandes, debes considerar crear tus iconos con las medidas:

> - 36 x 36 px  para el folder `/mipmap-ldpi`
> - 48 x 48 px  para el folder `/mipmap-mdpi`
> - 72 x 72 px  para el folder `/mipmap-hdpi`
> - 96 x 96 px  para el folder `/mipmap-xhdpi`
> - 144 x 144 px   para el folder `/mipmap-xxhdpi`
> - 192 x 192 px   para el folder `/mipmap-xxxhdpi`

También puedes agregar los graficos de icon launchers dentro de su respectivo folder `/drawable-`, pero por buena practica ahora deben estar dentro de `/mipmap-`

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html

---

> He creado un icono metiendo una imagen png para la aplicación mediante
>   "image assets"

Para el caso de launcher icons lo ideal es lo que comento, aunque si deseas agregar solo una imagen te aconsejo mejor usar un grafico vectorial que podría verse similar en todos los tamaños y resoluciones, pero debe ser agregado como "Vector Asset".

Comment: ok gracias por la info